# Running ArcGIS Python Script with PHP

Tags: php, python, wamp, arcgis

I'm trying to run from PHP (i'm using WAMP)a small python code that calls a Toolbox/Model that I created within ArcGIS 10.2.2. When I run the model from ArcGIS it works fine, same as when I run the python program directly by double-clicking it. I also tried executing it from a batch file; it all works. It just won't work when run from PHP... it get's stuck loading until after several minutes it tells me that the operation has timed out.

When I try running a different script that prints hello everything works fine.

The code:

```
import arcpy, arcinfo

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Network")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\My Toolboxes\DeliveryService.tbx", "Delivery")
arcpy.Routes_Delivery()

arcpy.CheckInExtension("Network")
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you searched the [gis.se] Stack Exchange for an answer to this?

Comment: @PolyGeo I did! Some time ago... unfortunately I couldn't find anything very useful for my issue